# How to get sshfs running on Mac OS X 10.6 64-bit?

Tags: 64-bit, ssh, xubuntu, sshfs, macfuse

There seem to be a couple of problems at play here. First let me describe my set-up:

I have a Xubuntu 11.04 file server that I can SSH into. I *believe* that machine has all the packages it needs on it to make this work. I SSH in from an iMac running 10.6.8 (64-bit Kernel and Extensions).

That works fine.

In order to make the [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) bit work I've installed [MacFUSE](http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/). This excellent project seems to have been abandoned unfortunately. In any case, there was a problem with MacFUSE-2.0.3,2.dmg as it is 32-bit. I've updated to the 2.15 beta but that's still 32-bit as you can see (I think it has a 64-bit prefPane???):

[image: MacFUSE]

Now I need the sshfs 'plugin' to complete this picture. A typical terminal error message looks as follows:

[image: error]

I've tried using [MacFusion](http://macfusionapp.org/) but that didn't work either. I've also tried the [sshfs.app](http://macfuse.googlecode.com/). I believe the problem lies in the 32-bitness of the MacFUSE system.

I *could* buy Xcode and compile FUSE and sshfs from source, but I'm looking for pre-compiled binaries if at all possible.

Any clues?

Comment: It's been about a year since I tried to get sshfs going on OSX, I tried for a few hours before rebooting in to Ubuntu and resuming use of my machine. Anyway +1 to the question. I sure hope someone actually gets it working on 10.6 and posts simple instructions to replicate. PS - I too was on a Core 2 machine - meaning 64bit.

Comment: Cheers. It's an absolute hair-puller. Tried for hours last night to get it going. Big shame because it'd be *so* good if it did work. Anyway, here's hoping someone has the magic spell required.

Answer (score 1):

Well, from the error messages the problem lies in that your shell does not have sshfs in PATH.

You can check your path with:

```
echo $PATH
```

and/or you can try to run it with full path like:

```
/path/to/your/sshfs .. and the rest of the params
```

Usually on *nix systems you can add to your path (assuming your shell is bash) by editing/creating this  `.bashrc` file to your home directory.

I'm not sure do you have `nano` editor available, but any editor will do (Word is not and editor).

```
nano -w ~/.bashrc
```

add a line to that file

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/your/sshfs/dir
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I'd love to confirm that this is the problem. I never thought of my path being the problem. Unfortunately I can't check if fixing my path helps because the Xubuntu box has bitten the dust and I'm on OS X 10.7 now. Perhaps someone else can try this out? FWIW: I bought a QNAP 2-bay NAS instead of having the huge fileserver. Thanks again for your input. Also, I might add that OS X has `nano` and most of the basic *nix tools available.

Comment: Well, we use Qnaps a lot. And especially the Pro versions are nice. And one of the reasons I love them is that they have ssh server on by default (configurable from settings) and you can try using sshfs against qnap (no point normally unless you're on a headless server without nfs or smb clients) so. `sshfs admin@YourQnapHost:/tmp /YourMOuntPoint`

Comment: Yeh, they're lovely machines. I haven't seen the need to SSH in as everything is local, but I may, for curiosity, take a look at SSH, et. al support. Thanks again.